# Error :Group function not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, aggregate-functions

```
select shipment_stop_d.shipment_gid,count(s_ship_unit_line.s_ship_unit_gid) 
from s_ship_unit_line,shipment_stop_d 
where shipment_stop_d.shipment_gid is not null 
and count(s_ship_unit_line.s_ship_unit_gid) > 200 
group by s_ship_unit_line.s_ship_unit_gid;
```

condition I need is how many `{(s_ship_unit_line.s_ship_unit_gid)}` are there whose count is more than 200 in table `s_ship_unit_line` for `shipment_gid` in table `shipment_stop_d`

Comment: What is the relationship between `s_ship_unit_line` and `shipment_stop_d`? As written this query will join every row in `s_ship_unit_line` to every line in `shipment_stop_d`, i.e. a Cartesian join. ???

Answer (score 2):

You have `count(s_ship_unit_line.s_ship_unit_gid) > 200` in the where clause, that's a rule violation.

`count` is a group function which may be allowed 
in the **select** list or in a **having by** clause.

Use

```
select d.shipment_gid,count(l.s_ship_unit_gid) 
  from s_ship_unit_line l join shipment_stop_d d 
    on ( d.id = l.shipment_id ) -- I assumed this columns for joining condition.
 where d.shipment_gid is not null 
 group by l.s_ship_unit_gid
having count(l.s_ship_unit_gid) > 200;
```

instead.

Comment: ok i used this commands   select distinct ssd.shipment_gid,count(sul.s_ship_unit_gid) as line_number
from s_ship_unit_line sul
join shipment_stop_d ssd on sul.s_ship_unit_gid = ssd.s_ship_unit_gid 
where ssd.shipment_gid is not null group by ssd.shipment_gid having count(sul.s_ship_unit_gid)>200;
 but problem is line number value is coming double of what is there. no idea why its getting multiplied by 2.

Comment: @ankitsingh first of all, no need to use `distinct`, there's already `group by` condition. I wonder the columns in the join condition `sul.s_ship_unit_gid` and `ssd.s_ship_unit_gid` primary or unique keys in their tables, respectively ?